# is there any way to add button to django admin?

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

i want a button to call a view function from django admin. i want my button here [my django admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVzei.png)

When i click on that button , it calls a specified view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the default django admin template. Please read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/overriding-templates/

Comment: can you explain step by step as there is no explanation for overriding admin template..

Comment: Sorry I can't. But everything that you need is at Django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates